# Why are answered questions appearing in the unanswered question tab?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I checked in the unanswered tab on the main site recently to see if there was anything I might be able to answer and saw that many of the quests had answers and had accepted and answer. Why are these questions appearing in that tab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two kinds of unanswered questions:

- **Questions with no answers.** This is what you are expecting.
- **Questions with no *upvoted* answers.** This is what you're seeing. The idea behind this class of unanswered questions is that an answer is only good insomuch as it's been vetted by the community.

The default is the latter, but you can switch between the two using the secondary tabs:

[image: Unanswered secondary tabs]

You shouldn't see accepted or upvoted answers in either tab: if you see that, it's likely due to the question *just* getting an accepted or upvoted answer and caching hasn't caught up yet.

Comment: That explains it thank you!